# Error while executing playbook to start ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have a playbook that starts an ec2 instance. But I keep getting the following error when I run it.

```
---

- name: Create an ec2 instance
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
      region: us-east-1
      instance_type: t2.micro
      ami: ami-01ac7d9c1179d7b74
      keypair: priyajdm

  tasks:

    - name: Create an ec2 instance
      ec2:
         key_name: "{{ keypair }}"
         group: launch-wizard-31
         instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
         image: "{{ ami }}"
         wait: true
         region: "{{ region }}"
         count: 1
         vpc_subnet_id: subnet-02f498e16fd56c277
         assign_public_ip: yes
      register: ec2
```

Error:
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: `AuthFailure`AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentialscb70bd1a-b7ec-41aa-895a-fabf9e0b6cfe
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553599571.08-120541135236553/AnsiballZ_ec2.py\", line 113, in \n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553599571.08-120541135236553/AnsiballZ_ec2.py\", line 105, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553599571.08-120541135236553/AnsiballZ_ec2.py\", line 48, in invoke_module\n    imp.load_module('**main**', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ec2_payload_hXpgWw/**main**.py\", line 1702, in \n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ec2_payload_hXpgWw/**main**.py\", line 1686, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ec2_payload_hXpgWw/**main**.py\", line 989, in create_instances\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/vpc/**init**.py\", line 1152, in get_all_subnets\n    return self.get_list('DescribeSubnets', params, [('item', Subnet)])\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py\", line 1186, in get_list\n    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)\nboto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized\n\n`AuthFailure`AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentialscb70bd1a-b7ec-41aa-895a-fabf9e0b6cfe\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

Comment: It says "AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials". That seems like a pretty clear error message.

Comment: Obviously, that was the first thing I checked when i got the error. My credentails very correct. I'm not sure why it isn't able to validate them

Comment: It's not obvious, actually: there isn't anything in your question that shows you have confirmed you are using valid credentials, and you didn't state explicitly that you had checked.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you keep your AWS credentials? You have 3 option:

1. Use boto configuration file
2. Set needed enviroment varaibles
3. Set EC2 module AWS credentials parameters in your task

Last options is the worst practice but easiest way to solve authentication problems.

Check the [EC2 Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_module.html)’s notes.

Comment: I have a credentials file inside my .aws directory. I have saved my aws credentials there.

Comment: Your credentials configured for AWS CLI. That is not related with Ansible. You should choose an option from my answer.

Comment: Also, I tried mentioning my credentails in the playbook tasks, still the same error.